# tab order between multiple groupbox's

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

I have multiple groupbox's : let's say

```
GroupBox 1 : Button 11, Button 12, Button 13
GroupBox 2 : Button 21, Button 22, Button 23
```

I have issues with the taborder, I want to do something like this :

```
Button 11 -> Button 22 -> Button 13  -> Button 21
```

I've tried a lot of things but none of them worked (Put all my groupboxes at the tabindex 0, then set the button's tabindex in the correct order). 
Thanks.

Comment: So you want to select them in this order: `Button 11 -> Button 22 -> Button 13  -> Button 21` how about telling us what its currently doing as 'not working' isnt very descriptive

Comment: What about `tabindex` property of your `button` controls?

Comment: @EpicKip I've edited my post with more informations.

Comment: @MuratSEKER I've tried with all the groupbox's tabindex at 0 but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Cesar Is does not work because it looks for the parent tabindex so it will select the groupbox's in order. Looking for a fix

Comment: @EpicKip Yeah thanks, I will maybe do that this way, I thought it was possible to do it with the TabOrder view ! Thanks anyways !

Comment: @Cesar No point ^^

Answer (score 1):

Follow this way.
View/Tab Order then select your `button` controls. When you do it your cursor will become a plus sign and you can change numbers whatever you want.

[image]

For me, it is looking like this and it is working fine. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in your way it will do : Button 2 -> Button 1 -> button 3 -> Button 4. And I would like it to be Button 2 -> Button 3 -> Button 1 -> Button 4. So I would like to go from GroupBox 1 to GroupBox 2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There is Property called TabIndex

1. Set Tabindex for Button 11=1
2. Set Tabindex for Button 22=2
3. Set Tabindex for Button 13=3
4. Set Tabindex for Button 21=4